# Route all Ipv4 traffic over a 6in4 tunnel using RouterOS 6.x

Tags: ipv6, tunneling

Would it be possible to route all IPv4 traffic over an IPv6 tunnel?

Let me elaborate, let's say I establish a tunnelbroker (HE) 6in4 tunnel, using IPv4 (duh!), but then I want to relay all my IPv4 traffic over the IPv6 tunnel, so, in other words make this IPv6 link my default gateway for all internet traffic (IPv6 and IPv4).

The hardware available is:

- Mikrotik RouterBoard RB750 with RouterOS 6.x
- ADSL ISP with one dynamic public IPv4 address.
- PCs, Phones, etc...

Answer (score 2):

A `6in4` tunnel transports IPv6 packets, so it is not possible to transport IPv4 packets in such a tunnel.

What you can do if you want all your traffic to go through the tunnel is to change your local network to IPv6-only. Usually this limits you to reaching IPv6-capable sites, but when you combine it with NAT64/DNS64 then you would be able to reach IPv4 sites through NAT64. There is a list of public NAT64 gateways [here](http://hydra.geht.net/tino/english/opinion/ipv6/ipv4/list/).

I wouldn't recommend such a setup though, you'll end up with horrible routing. This will not be good for your latency and bandwidth.

Comment: Given that he is using a tunnel provided by Hurricane Electric, it might make sense to also use the DNS64 and NAT64 operated by Hurricane Electric.

Comment: @kasperd: do you have a pointer to information about their NAT64 setup? I didn't even know they had one.

Comment: I tried looking for some official information about it, but I couldn't find any. Searching for the IP address of the DNS64 server lead me to this URL: http://www.excivity.com/ComputeCycle/shmooconipv6dns/